# Excel Logical operators inside If loop

Tags: excel, loops, logical-operators

So this works:

```
=IF(OR(D2="MEXICO",D2="TURKEY",D2="CHINA",D2="BRAZIL",D2="INDIA",D2="INDONESIA",D2="POLAND",D2="COLOMBIA",D2="ARGENTINA",D2="PHILIPPINES"),D2,"Others")
```

But this doesn't

```
=IF(D2=OR("MEXICO","TURKEY","CHINA","BRAZIL","INDIA","INDONESIA","POLAND","COLOMBIA","ARGENTINA","PHILIPPINES"),D2,"Others")
```

Is there a way to get around writing D2= inside every single time? I am looking to see if the criteria can be used in multiple places .. say in a different sheet I also have country names, but just not in column "D".

Comment: `or()` expects logical arguments, e.g. true/false values. `d2="mexico"` will return true/false, but `"mexico"` by itself is just a string, and is not true/false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you create a list of country names in a column in a sheet somewhere and use that as a look up where ever you need it. You can create a separate sheet with this data, say datasheet.

Let's say you have a list of countries in A1:A25 of datasheet, you can then do something like this:

```
    =IF(COUNTIF(datasheet!A1:datasheet!A25, D2) <> 0, D2, "Other")
```

Additionally, I would create a [named range](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA010147120.aspx#BMquickly_name_a_cell_or_range_of_cells) for the set of country names if I expect them to change in the future. This way my formulas will refer to the name and if I add countries I do not have to change the formulas.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,{"MEXICO","TURKEY"},1,0)),"Others",D2)
```

Futhermore, as @barryhoudini suggest, in excel 2007 or later you can use:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,{"MEXICO","TURKEY"},1,0),"Others")
```

Comment: That's good! In Excel 2007 or later you could possibly use IFERROR like this - `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,{"MEXICO","TURKEY"},1,0),"Others")`

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to use `OR` but you need to change the syntax a little - like this

`=IF(OR(D2={"MEXICO","TURKEY","CHINA","BRAZIL","INDIA","INDONESIA","POLAND","COLOMBIA","ARGENTINA","PHILIPPINES"}),D2,"Others")`

Comment: Yes, that's possible pnuts - I just considered suggesting such a thing......, but if using a range I think I'd prefer the `COUNTIF` option to avoid `CSE`

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, this should work for you:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D2, {"MEXICO","TURKEY","CHINA","BRAZIL","INDIA","INDONESIA","POLAND","COLOMBIA","ARGENTINA","PHILIPPINES"}, 0)), "Others", D2)
```